# How to install and run brew.sh in command prompt?

Tags: cmd, homebrew

I have a error in command prompt:

> brew is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Did you follow the install instructions on https://brew.sh/ ?

Comment: I check instruction in the brew.sh but no clarify for windows

Comment: `brew` is a package manager for **macOS** (or Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew is only for MacOSX.

For Windows you can try with followings:-

```
Chocolatey
Npackd
Scoop
OneGet for Windows 10
```